# What to do with corrupted vim display?

Tags: vim, vimrc

What is the best way to deal with remnant text in vim editor? I'm ssh to a remote terminal using Xquartz, and edit my code using vim. When I hit return, there remains text displayed in the current line, even thought they are actually moved to the next line. It becomes hard to read and I have to restart vim every now and then. Is there a solution for that problem?

For example: if I add `set cursorline` in my `.vimrc` and then move the cursor around it will show like this, and `:redraw!` won't fix the problem:
[image: Screenshot of my xterm]

Comment: you have got to do ^L, redraw

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to have the correct terminal type in your `TERM` variable, and inform the remote host of your terminal size with `stty rows <rows> columns <cols>`.

Nowadays, I only have to do this when dealing with embedded hosts over serial consoles; the SSH protocol knows how to communicate these settings from the local system to a remote Unix-like kernel (or to generate the settings in the case of a client like PuTTY).

Maybe you have some shell `.profile` script on the remote host which is putting an inappropriate value into `TERM` or messing up the TTY info with bogus `stty` commands.

[UPDATE]

The example display now shown in the question looks very much like horizontal scrolling. Just type <kbd>0</kbd> to jump to the leftmost column.

You can disable horizontal scrolling using `:set wrap`; then long lines are wrapped. To enable horizontal scrolling again, use `:set nowrap`.

Comment: Thanks for the input, I am new to vim or Linux in general. Can you show me in more detail how to set it up? And I just `ls -a` in my `$HOME`, and there is no `.profile`

Comment: `.profile` is both a literal filename and often used as a handy short-hand for "shell startup scripts".  bash, for example, uses /etc/profile, ~/.profile, and ~/.bash_profile on login shells and ~/.bashrc for non-login shells.  And some others which i can't remember right now (insufficient coffee error), see the man page for your shell for details.

Comment: a followup question: If I do want to keep the horizontal line, but Also keep the display updated whenever I move my cursor, what should I do. I did find a temporary solution: when I enter vim, I type `:!clear` then hit `enter`, then everything works fine for the vim session. I don't know how does it work, or how to achieve it without manually doing it everytime I vim